# Silent Progress ? PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need help with Powershell
this is my code;

```
$Features = @(
    "MediaPlayback"
    "Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features"
    "Printing-XPSServices-Features"
    "SMB1Protocol"
    "WCF-Services45"
    "Xps-Foundation-Xps-Viewer"
    )

Foreach ($Feature in (Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online).FeatureName) {
    If ($Feature -in $Features) {
        Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $Feature -NoRestart
        Write-Host "Disabled Optional Feature $Feature"
    }
}
```

and this is what i see
Path   :
Online : True

Disabled Optional Feature Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features

Path   :
Online : True

Disabled Optional Feature Printing-XPSServices-Features

Path   :
Online : True

Disabled Optional Feature WCF-Services45

Path   :
Online : True

Disabled Optional Feature MediaPlayback

Path   :
Online : True

I just Want to Hide
Path :
Online : True
And ThankYOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppress the output from `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature` by piping to `Out-Null`, or by assigning it to the automatic `$null` variable:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $Feature -NoRestart |Out-Null
# or
$null = Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $Feature -NoRestart
```